# how to estimate CTR (ctr-click-through-rate)?

Tags: estimation, uncertainty

How many times should a banner be shown to estimate its click-through-rate (CTR)? For example, if a banner was shown $x$ times, and was clicked $y$ times.

$$\text{CTR} = \frac{y}{x}$$

How could I evaluate inaccuracy of this value?

Answer (score 1):

The variance of your estimator is $p(1-p)\over x$, where $p$ is the true proportion of people who click-through. You can estimate this by using $\hat p$ for $p$, which for you is given by $\hat p = {y \over x}$.

Comment: Assuming (i) independence and (ii) that there's no heterogeneity in click through rates